# Can I use gradle:2.2.0-alpha2 with build-tools 24.0.0 rc4 ?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, build-tools

is there any way how to use gradle:2.2.0-alpha2 with build-tools 24.0.0 rc4 ? I used  gradle:2.2.0-alpha**3** but there is an bug which cause invalid apk-signing so i can not upload new version of my app to GP. The solution is to use older version of gradle. Unfortunately i get this error :

```
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc4
```

I can not use older version like 23.0.1 because it causes several issues with other libraries which i currently use.

So, I just need to know if it's posible to use gradle:2.2.0-alpha2 with build-tools 24.0.0 rc4 together.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you trying it and see?

Comment: When i tried it i got that error which i mentioned above. I hoped that somebody might have known how to fix it...